# Should SMTP close socket after all data is send?

Tags: email, smtp

I am trying to implement SMTP server based on Gevent, named gsmtpd

https://github.com/34nm/gsmtpd

However after 3 weeks logging in my production server, I found most of webmail providers' client won't closed socket after they had send all data.
Causing a lots of log says socket timeout.

Should I close the socket with Bye after they send all data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the client sends the message, your SMTP server should send a `250 2.0.0 Ok` to indicate that the message was received.  Then, the client should either send `quit` to end the session, or `rset` to send another message.

If the client sends `quit`, then your SMTP server can send a `221 2.0.0 Bye` and close the socket.

If the client sends `rset`, then your SMTP server can send a `250 2.0.0 Ok` and prepare to receive another message.

If the client sends anything other than `quit` or `rset` (or if your SMTP server times-out waiting for a command from the client), your server can send a `421 2.0.0 Bye` and close the socket.

Comment: Actually RSET command is for aborting already started mail transaction (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321#section-4.1.1.5).  New transaction is initiated using the MAIL command (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321#section-4.1.1.2).  AFAIK, that is the way most servers work.  So after receiving the message you should expect QUIT, RSET or MAIL.

Answer (score 0):

You should send `quit` or more `mail` after receiving `250` in response to the end of the data. `rset` and the other commands that are allowed after `ehlo` are also allowed here.

Closing immediately after sending the data payload will possibly get it rejected, you should wait for the `250` response.  This is no small thing, it's basically transfer of responsibility for the message.

Closing the connection after receining the 250, but withouth sending `quit` will not cause any data loss, but may waste disc on the server as it will probably log this irregular behaviour.